# Swift 3 OS X app launch on startup

Tags: macos, autostart

I just wrote my first application in Swift 3 for OS X.  How can I configure this app to launch when the user logs in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Swift Cocoa app launch on startup on OS X 10.11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35339277/make-swift-cocoa-app-launch-on-startup-on-os-x-10-11)

Comment: No, this isn't my post.

Comment: Clarified that auto-launch is the goal.

Comment: @Musyanon agreed that isn't your post, but it seems to answer your question.

Comment: @Richard I have already see this post but the solution use old version of Swift and doesn't work with Swift 3 I have alrealdy try :(

Comment: @Musyanon Actually, the solution there doesn't show any code; it's just links.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, but there are some restrictions. First, the application must reside in the Applications folder. Second, I've seen it recommended that a "helper" app be included in the target app bundle to perform the actual startup… but I must admit that I don't know why that is necessary.

```
if SMLoginItemSetEnabled(appBundleIdentifier as CFString, true) {
    log.info("Successfully added login item.")
} else {
    log.warning("Failed to add login item.")
}
```

The last argument tells the system whether to add (true) or remove (false) the application from startup. Google `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`for more details. Otherwise I am wrestling with this myself and I'd welcome someone to expand on this.

Comment: Applications are not able to use their own bundle identifier in this way, so that is why many choose to use a second target. Reference: https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/27/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/